# Zuul and Consul integration issue

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, consul, netflix-zuul

I have problem setting up Spring Cloud application with Zuul and Consul service discovery. I have Consul server agent installed and running locally:

```
./src/main/bash/local_run_consul.sh
```

When I run Spring Boot application with `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.RouteLocator]: Factory method 'routeLocator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate service in consul agent: edge-server-8765
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 73 more
```

Sources:

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.2.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

war {
    baseName = 'edge-server'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

mainClassName = 'com.akamai.pulsar.onboarding.edge.app.ZuulApplication'

dependencies {
    providedRuntime("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-undertow")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zuul:1.0.0.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-consul-all:1.0.0.M3')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**application.yml**

```
info:
  component: Zuul Server

endpoints:
  restart:
    enabled: true
  shutdown:
    enabled: true
  health:
    sensitive: false

zuul:
  ignoredServices: "*"
  routes:
    test-api:
      path: /test-api/**

server:
  port: 8765

logging:
  level:
    ROOT: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
```

**bootstrap.yml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: edge-server
  cloud:
    consul:
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
      config:
        enabled: true
```

**ZuulApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(ZuulApplication.class).web(true).run(args);
    }
}
```

**Note:** When I comment out the `@EnableZuulProxy` annotation, my service runs without problems and is registered in Consul correctly.

I have no idea what to do. Maybe there is some bad dependency issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: spring-cloud-consul is built for spring-boot 1.3.x, that may be a problem. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: the version of spring-cloud-zuul it would work with is 1.1.0.M4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/112) in spring-cloud-consul with `ConsulDiscoveryClient.getLocalServiceInstance`.

Setting `zuul.ignoreLocalService: false` will work around it for now.

Comment: This is fixed in snapshots now.

Comment: Thank you very much @spencergibb Your solution is correct.