# Micro-services: Zuul & consul in Spring cloud application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, consul, netflix-zuul

I'm trying to create a Spring cloud microservice application using Zuul and Consul.

I have 2 components in my project:

1. api-gateway microservice using Zuul
2. Hello world microservice (a simple hello world Rest Webservice)

Here is the code of The api-gateway:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableZuulProxy
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 public class ZuulApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
  }

 }
```

The pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Brixton.M3</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.cloud.consul.version>1.0.0.M4</spring.cloud.consul.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zuul</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.cloud.consul.version}</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

application.yml

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    hello1:
     path: /hello1/**
     serviceId: microservice-example

logging:
  level:
   org.springframework: INFO
   com.netflix: DEBUG
```

bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: edge-server

 cloud:
   consul:
    config:
      enabled: true
      host: localhost
      port: 8500
```

Here is the code of hello microservice:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableConfigServer
 @EnableDiscoveryClient
 @RestController
 public class Application {

 @RequestMapping(value="/hello1",method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String hello() {
    System.out.print("hello1");
    return "Hello1";
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(true).run(args);
 }
}
```

bootstrap.yml:
   spring:
     application:
       name: microservice-example
     profiles:
       active: native

```
 cloud:
  consul:
   config:
    enabled: true
    host: localhost
    port: 8500
```

But, when I start the api-gateway I got the following exception:

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed     to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.RouteLocator]: Factory method 'routeLocator' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate service in consul agent: edge-server
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
... 69 common frames omitted
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate service in consul agent: edge-server
at org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulDiscoveryClient.getLocalServiceInstance(ConsulDiscoveryClient.java:66) ~[spring-cloud-consul-discovery-1.0.0.M4.jar:1.0.0.M4]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zuul and Consul integration issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782873/zuul-and-consul-integration-issue)

Comment: Already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33782873/zuul-and-consul-integration-issue and already fixed in snapshots.

Comment: you recommend which version of spring-cloud-starter-consul?

Comment: The latest is part of Brixton.M3 (1.0.0.M4), but it doesn't have that fix which is just a few days old.

Comment: In this example I work with The last version (1.0.0.M4). please refer to pom of the project.

Comment: It's not fixed in 1.0.0.M4, it's fixed in snapshots.

Comment: Now, it's wok with the snapshots but when I test my service the browser requires authentication. Have you any idea?

Comment: when I deleted Spring security dependecy, I haven't exception but I have this message in browser: Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in Brixton.M3 (1.0.0.M5). As mentioned above this was an issue with spring-cloud-consul. The new version is working fine